# How do I randomize the enum type data with "randomize() with"?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to randomize enum type data with `randomize() with`. I declared
`color_e` and randomized it with `!obj.randomize() with {my_color == RED;})`

```
typedef enum logic [2:0] {RED=3'b001, GREEN=3'b010, BLUE=3'b011} color_e;
    
class my_class;
  color_e my_color;
endclass

module top;
  my_class obj =new();
  
  initial begin
    if (!obj.randomize() with {my_color == RED;}) begin
      $display("Randomization failed!");
    end else begin
      $display("Randomization succeeded! my_color = %0d", obj.my_color);
    end
  end
endmodule
```

After execute it, I get the error about randomize fail, but I don't why the error happened.

```
color_e my_color;
                 |
xmsim: *W,RNDXZW (./testbench.sv,4|17): Constraints reference an X/Z value.
    if (!obj.randomize() with {my_color == RED;}) begin
                     |
xmsim: *W,SVRNDF (./testbench.sv,11|21): The randomize method call failed. The unique id of the failed randomize call is 0.
```

How do I randomize the `enum` type data with `randomize() with`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the variable to be a random variable using the `rand` keyword:

```
class my_class;
    rand color_e my_color;
endclass
```

That eliminates the `*W` warning messages you received.

This should be done for all variable types, not just `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting an error message is you did not declare `my_color` as a `rand` class member *and* its initial value is 3'bx. So when calling `obj.randomize() with {my_color == RED;}`, it thinks you have the constraint `3'bx == RED` which is not a valid constraint.

Adding the `rand` qualifier makes your code work as you intended.